# Error when compiling: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c

I have `interface.c`:

```
#include "interface.h"

int main(){
}

int foo(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

And `interface.h`:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_INTERFACE_H
#define UNTITLED_INTERFACE_H

int foo(int a, int b);

#endif //UNTITLED_INTERFACE_H
```

Now, `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "interface.h"

int main(){

    printf("%d \n ", foo(3,4));

}
```

I compiled `gcc test.c -o test` but get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _main in test-9668b6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know why? All files are in the same folder! I searched online I still see that I am following the right steps! Can someone hint me?
Thank you.

Comment: `gcc test.c interface.c -o test` will fix that problem and create another.

Comment: two main() functions allowed??